# Web scraping using rvest: css selector to get "more text"

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I am looking at an example of scraping text data from a website and struggling to get all the text from a particular section specifically where that text box has a field called “Read More”.

I have tried different css selectors (identified using Selector Gadget) with no success and the captured text is not all the text available.

Any ideas on how to get the complete text field?

Thanks!

```
library(rvest)

link = "https://www.property24.com/for-sale/camps-bay/cape-town/western-cape/11014/109734849"

html_link = read_html(link)

# Method 1
text1 = html_link %>%
  html_nodes(css = ".js_readMoreText") %>%
  html_text()
text1

# Method 2
text2 = html_link %>%
  html_nodes(css = ".js_readMore") %>%
  html_text()
text2

# Method 3
text3 = html_link %>%
  html_nodes(css = ".expanded , .js_readMoreText") %>%
  html_text()
text3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That content is stored in the content attribute of a meta tag. You can select as follows:

```
library(rvest)

link <- "https://www.property24.com/for-sale/camps-bay/cape-town/western-cape/11014/109734849"
html_link <- read_html(link)

description <- html_link %>%
  html_node('[property="og:description"]') %>%
  html_attr('content')
```

Comment: Would it be possible to share how you identified that the content was in a meta tag? I used Selector Gadget on the webpage and it would help to understand how you pulled it. Thank you!

Comment: I opened the webpage and used the dev tools to go to elements tab then did a text search for some of the read more text.